# Server shuts down when running sql query

Tags: windows, sql, unexpected-shutdown

- Sql Server 2005 Windows Server 2003 64 bit 8 processors
- 3 volumes with at least 100 gigs free on each

I was adding an sql index for a table with millions of rows and the server shut down. Nothing in the event log other than the last shut down was unexpected. Upon restart the db is suspect and I take the steps to recover it. I'm running a dbcheck for about 30 mins then another shut down. This pattern is easily repeatable meaning that it has happened every time I've attempted it.

If I don't attempt to recover this db and let it sit the server doesn't crash otherwise. It ran for a week before I noticed the db was broken. Meaning, under regular load, this server doesn't crash. This isn't a prod system but for testing.

I'm guessing its overheating though nothing is telling me that. The server has not had heat issues in the past and it was designed with heavy duty heat sinks and has a good air flow.

I suppose it could be a faulty memory stick. I'll run a memory check in a moment.

Comment: You could install speed fan and watch your temps. Anything up to 80c should be fine.

Comment: The memory check is a good idea. Keep us posted with the results.

Comment: Server make and model?

Comment: Never so much mind the temps, mind the voltages, tell us about your power supplies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your System Failure and Recovery options to create at least a minidump on crashes.  When the computer crashes next, either install/use [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) to analyze the crash dump.  Or if its a minidump, you can upload it to an online crash analysis site like: http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

1. Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab, and then under Startup and Recovery, click Settings (or Startup and Recovery).